# How to check if the segwit2x fork was adopted?

Tags: electrum, blockchain-fork, segwit2x

SegWit2x was scheduled to happen today at BTC block 501451 (http://b2x-segwit.io).

How do I check if the fork was adopted and by whom?

Electrum wallet docs (http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/hardfork.html) say the app will detect a blockchain split, but mine didn't notice anything. Does this means the fork wasn't successful?

Comment: This looks deceptive, as it seems unrelated to the earlier fork proposal with the same name.

Comment: @PieterWuille indeed, I've seen many comments against it, but I'm very new to BTC and I don't get how it could be a scam - I mean, could they steal regular (unforked) BTC with this? What they win with the fork?

Comment: The scam is that they may confuse newbies that their operation is part of a large movement rather than some guy co-opting their name. Thus making them think they're buying something far more valuable than it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an [official announcement of the fork having taken place](https://medium.com/@Segwit2X/the-long-awaited-launch-of-new-bitcoin-segwit2x-fork-finally-took-place-aa57af577655). According to the [official website](http://b2x-segwit.io/) the fork is planned for block 501451 which has indeed occurred about 8 hours ago.

The [stats of their mining pool](http://pool.b2x-segwit.io/stats) don't look to promising though, but it might be too early to tell. Also keep an eye out on their [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SegWit2xReload/) and other social media.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm very new to this... How can I find out servers using the forked branch of the blockchain instead of the "regular" branch, so I can point my electrum wallet to them and check my B2X account?

Comment: I've searched for https://bitnodes.earn.com/nodes/?q=segwit2x and found some nodes reporting this string in the user agent, are these the forked nodes?

Comment: Those could still be signalling their support for the original segwit2x... I would look around the mining pools claiming to be supporting the current fork as stated on the official website.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the lateral answer, but I feel this needs to be here:

This project appears to be co-opting the name of the New York Agreement's fork attempt. Likely, they are trying to cash in on the name recognition in order to make their project seem more established and valuable than it is.

This project is not supported by the principal actors behind the original SegWit2x fork attempt, nor does this coin seem to have any of the original movement's industry support.

Please do your due diligence before throwing money at this coin.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Actually, all I want is to sell any B2X I get due to the fork, there are too many signs that this "project" is not what it looks like.